# Slick 3.0.3 TableQuery where are the insert and insertOrUpdate methods?

Tags: scala, slick

I'm using Slick 3.0.3 and can't find any `insert` or `insertOrUpdate` functions supposedly available in `slick.lifted.TableQuery` my IDE can't see anything even close and when I go to the Scala Docs [slick.lifted.TableQuery](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.3/api/index.html#slick.lifted.TableQuery) I see that these methods are no longer available ... how can you upsert now on Slick 3.0.3? e.g.

```
import slick.lifted.TableQuery 

// generated code 
class Fund(_tableTag: Tag) extends Table[FundRow](_tableTag, "fund") {...}
lazy val Fund = new TableQuery(tag => new Fund(tag))

// client code
val fundQuery = TableQuery[Fund]
fundQuery.insertOrUpdate(...) // not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have access to the table functions you need to add an import for the API of the driver you are using; e.g., for H2:

```
import skick.driver.H2Driver.api._
```

At that point you should be able to use the functions to insert into the database:

```
val insertAction: DBIO[Int] = fundQuery += aFund
val insertOrUpdateAction: DBIO[Int] = fundQuery.insertOrUpdate(aFund)
```

It's worth noting that these functions return a `DBIO` that then you need to run using a database instance in order to get a `Future`:

```
val result: Future[Int] = someDb.run(insertAction)
```

Comment: Oh yeah implicits bite me again :((((